# How to Connect odoo Cloud with local network LDAP

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, odoo, ldap, odoo-16

we had odoo app installed on our local network , users use to login using there session ldap
recenetly we just migrate our odoo app moved from our local server to cloud.
my question how the users can connect using ldap if the active directory is in local different network .

note  : Our active direcotry is schronized with AzureAD
We use FortiGate as Firewall

i didn't try anything yet i was searching for answer since i'm new to this